# Count the number of child div inside parent div and align the child divs in the middle of the parent div

Tags: javascript

I have 8 child divs inside a parent div. I have to count the width of the parent div and divide the width with the number of child width and place them in the middle of the parent div using javascript

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var divFooterWidth = $('#divFooter').width();
  var temp = $('#divFooter div.div1');

Comment: How in the middle? Vertically, so all 8 next to each other, or horizontally, so all 8 below each other?

Comment: all 8 next to each other

Comment: i did align them next to each other but i need to place them in the middle of the parent div with javascript.

Comment: To put them in the middle, give the parent a css ```display: table-cell;``` and ```vertical-align: middle;```

Comment: Edit your original question with your code, not inside the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the width of the parent and split it into 8. Then you can set the width of the children by using `.css('width')`. In my example I set the height the same as the width, so you can clearly see there are 8 divs. If you want the height to be max, just set the css to 100%.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var countDiv = $('.inner').length,
    outerWidth = $('.outer').css('width').replace('px', ''),
    singleWidth = outerWidth / countDiv + 'px';

$('.inner').css('width', singleWidth)
           .css('height', singleWidth);
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}
```

**JSFiddle** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gng0b7zy/)